# FullCalendar - Display icon on each day based on event criteria

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar.  I would like to display an icon in each day cell that matches certain event criteria.

More specifically, I would like to display a warning & tooltip if the 'notes' field in my event feed is not empty.

I am able to display an icon on each day, regardless of any events, but I want to take it one step further.

Here is how I am displaying on each day using dayRender:

```
dayRender: function ( date, cell) {
cell.prepend('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}
```

I can get the tooltip and icon to show up correctly if I use eventRender, but then the icon shows up as part of the event....which I don't want.  I want the icon part of the day cell.

Here is my eventRender:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) { 
                if (event.notes) { 
                    $(element).tooltip({title: event.notes});
        element.find(".fc-title").prepend("&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "<i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i>"); 
        }
    }
```

Here is my event feed:

```
$event_array[] = array(
        'id' => $calrow['id'],
        'title' => $calrow['available'],
        'start' => $calrow['start_date'],
        'end' => $calrow['end_date'],
        'notes' => $notes,
        'price' => '$'.$calrow['nightly_price'],
        'confirmationcode' => $calrow['confirmation_code'],
        'status' => $calrow['status'],
        'available' => $available
```

);

Is it possible to make the dayRender based on specific event criteria?  Do I use a combination of dayRender and eventRender?

Comment: better to make it event-specific surely? A day can have an infinite number of events in it, potentially, so how would each day know what to display if there was more than one event? Would it look in each one and only display the warning if all the notes were populated, or if at least one was populated? The rule is not clear, from your description.

Comment: My apologies for not articulating...I'm building a reservation/booking system.  A user may enter 'notes' on any calendar day (notes to themselves such as when to hire a cleaner, guests checking that day).  If making it event specific is better practice, is there a way to display the icon in the day container of the calendar, instead of in the event container?  For example in fc-day-top instead of fc-title?

Comment: You say "A user may enter 'notes' on any calendar day", but looking at your data structure that isn't true. The user may enter notes on an _event_, not a whole day. That's clear from your PHP. So again I ask: if, on any given day, there are multiple events, when should the icon be displayed? If at least one event has notes? If all of them have notes? It's still not clear. IMO I think it would be better to display the icon within the event container, because clearly (from the data structure) the note relates to that specific event, not to any others.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point.  Is there a way to display the icon outisde the event container?

Comment: yeah of course, you can put it wherever you like, it's your page. Maybe during "eventRender" would be a sensible place to write some code for that, where you could get access to the event data, and also manipulate the calendar HTML, since by then the rest of the calendar is rendered on the screen.

Comment: Ok, that's where I got stuck and hence posted the question here.  I don't know how to do that.  I've tried doing the following, but it's not working:           
    eventRender: function(event, element) { 
        if (event.notes) { 
         $(element).tooltip({title: event.notes});
            element.find(".fc-day-top").prepend("&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "<i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i>"); 
         }
        }

Comment: And I've tried repacling 'fc-day-top' with 'fc-day-number' but that doesn't do it either

Comment: `element` in eventRender is the event element. .find() finds things within that element.Things related to the whole day (e.g. day-top) are unlikely to be within that element, because they're related to more than just one event. Also which view type are we talking about here? The HTML structure is different for agenda, month, basic and timeline views

Comment: Sorry, I am referring to the month view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Day cells in the month view are rendered like this:

```
<td class="fc-day-top fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2017-11-02">
```

Therefore you can find a particular day cell quite easily:

```
$('.fc-day-top[data-date="2017-11-02"]')
```

Within the eventRender callback, you can use the event's start time to make this dynamically relate to the correct day for the event:

```
eventRender: function(event, element)
{
  $('.fc-day-top[data-date="' + event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + '"]').append("Hi");
},
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/68/ for a working example.

You may append anything you like in place of "Hi", of course.

Note that, as per the working example, this still has the drawback that it may append the same thing more than once, if there are multiple events on a given day.

Comment: Thank you.  How do I apply the tooltip (from my event render) to the "Hi" ?

Comment: To do that you should just be able replace `.append("Hi")` with `.tooltip({title: event.notes})` I think