# Add Icon to each day in FullCalendar Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I have a `FullCalendar` and I want to add icons to each day. Please note that I have already done research on the issue, including these answers on SO:

1. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906572/fullcalendar-how-can-i-display-an-icon-on-each-day-of-the-month-using-the-funct) Issue is that there does not seem to be a `dayRender` method.
2. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564120/fullcalendar-display-icon-on-each-day-based-on-event-criteria) Works good if the events are single day. Does not work for multi-day events
3. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61632845/fullcalendar-add-custom-button-to-each-day) Same problem as in 1.
4. I have checked the [Documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular) of FullCalendar/Angular and the [given examples](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/blob/master/angular/src/app/app.component.ts)

Either the method `dayRender` does not exists or I am not able to call it correctly.

What I am currently doing:

```
 <full-calendar ... (dayRender)="dayRender(date, cell)"></full-calendar>
```

Please note that:

1. I have only posted the relevant parts
2. I want to add icons to each day
3. I want to make them **clickable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer only solves `2.`. I am still unable to make the icons clickable.

To achieve this functionality you need to add the event listeners like this:

```
(dayRender)="dayRender($event)"
```

Then inside of *your* `dayRender` function, you receive an object with the following properties: `date` (of type Date), `el` (which is the specific element) and `view`1 (of type TimeGridView).

To add an icon to each day you need something like this:

```
dayRender(dayToBeRendered) {
  const imgElement: HTMLElement = document.createElement('img');
  // add the correct attributes to your img element
  dayToBeRendered.el.appendChild(divElement);
}
```